# Vertica copy from local file, handling connection resetting

Tags: python, logging, vertica

Hello I am new to Python. I have over 5000 .csv.gz files to be loaded on vertica data base. The server disconnects after 10 minutes, thus all 5000 files cannot be copied without re-setting the server connection.

I have two basic problems here:

1. How can I keep track of copy commands successfully executed?
2. How can I re-set the connection and restart from last failed command?

The code I am using is:

```
import pyodbc
conn = pyodbc.connect("DSN=Vertica_SG;SERVER=54.169.66.95;DATABASE=xyzdwh;PORT=5433;UID=abc123;PWD=abc123")
cursor = conn.cursor()
cursor.execute("Copy schema1.table1 from local 'E:\\folder1\\table1.csv.gz' GZIP with Delimiter ',' direct;")
cursor.execute("Copy schema1..table2 from local 'E:\\folder1\\table2.csv.gz' GZIP with Delimiter ',' direct;")

...
[5000 such execute commands]
...

print("All done")
```

Comment: What happens when the server connection is reset, does it throw an Exception?

Answer (score 1):

I suggest you use the `STREAM NAME` option when you load your data.

```
Copy schema1.table1 from local 'E:\folder1\table1.csv.gz' STREAM NAME 'E:\folder1\table1.csv.gz' GZIP with Delimiter ',' direct;
```

Then run a query on the stream loads that were successful and remove them from your list.

```
SELECT * FROM v_monitor.load_streams WHERE stream_name = 'My stream name';
```

Also it's good to see the `rejected_row_count` column value in the `load_streams` table as it will tell you how many rows were rejected.

You can use `CURRENT_LOAD_SOURCE()` as well, with this you will need to add a new column to your table.

But this is used when I do loads from different locations(parallel), and I can identify better which file failed during load.

```
--create the table 
create table bla(email varchar2(50),source varchar2(200));

--load the table using the CURRENT_LOAD_SOURCE() as a filler for the source column
COPY bla (email, source AS CURRENT_LOAD_SOURCE()) FROM '/home/dbadmin/data*' DELIMITER ',';

select * from bla limit 1;

                        email                     |  source
    ----------------------------------------------+----------
      Steven.Kastrinakis@advantagepharmacy.com.au | data.csv
```